# Ошибка C1854 нельзя перезаписать данные, сформированные во время создания предкомпилированного заголовка в объектном файле:

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую, уж не знаю сколько я борюсь с данной ошибкой и всё таки как-то забываю и перекомпилирую проект по 8-10 минут. 
Но пришла пора подключить еще 1 большую библиотеку и без предкомпилированного закоголвка уже точно не обойтись.

```
Ошибка  C1854 нельзя перезаписать данные, сформированные во время создания предкомпилированного заголовка в объектном файле: c:\users\...\source\repos\...\...\..\myname.obj    ... c:\users\...\source\repos\...\...
```

Действовал по инструкции , во все CPP "main.h" (это у меня заголовок).
Очистил проект , создал предкомпилирумый заголовок , всё хорошо. Но как только меняю флаг на "Использовать" вылазит данная ошибка. 
Вообщем буду очень рад , если кто то подскажет решение данной проблемы. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944429/error-c1854-cannot-overwrite-information-formed-during-creation-of-the-precompi

Comment: Ну если я правильно понял всю трактовку , то необходимо поставить во все CPP файлы , ваш "main.h"(допустим) и у всех cpp файлов установить создать предкомпилируемый заголовок. После этого сменить флаг на использовать. Это у меня и сделано. Но бьёт ошибку всё равно